# Unknown column 'c1' in 'field list' mysql>

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create database calificaciones;


Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)


mysql> use calificaciones;
Database changed

mysql>  create table prom(materia varchar(20),c1 float(3),c2 float(3),c3 float(3),c4 float(3),promedio float(3) not null);

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)




mysql>  delimiter //

mysql>  CREATE TRIGGER pumped BEFORE INSERT ON prom

    ->    FOR EACH ROW

    ->      IF NEW.c1 > 0 THEN

    ->      SET NEW.promedio = (c1+ c2+ c3+ c4)/4;

    ->      END IF;//

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)


mysql> DELIMITER ;



mysql>  INSERT INTO prom(materia,c1,c2,c3,c4,promedio) values("ingles",6,5,7,9,2);
```

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'c1' in 'field list'
>       mysql>

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que esta incorrecta la forma en la que tratas de resolver le problema.

- Primero: Si deseas Insertar el promedio de cada materia, es un valor nuevo entonces debes usar el prefijo `NEW` para cada una de las columnas involucradas en la operación
- Segundo: No veo sentido al usar un condicional `IF` en tu trigger pues se supone que si vas a calcular el promedio por cada renglón antes de que se inserte entonces la columna `c1` no posee valor entonces la condición de mayor a 0 no se cumpliría
- Tercero: Dentro de la sentencia de `INSERT` al menos por lo que entiendo de tu ejercicio no deberías indicar de forma explícita ni la columna `promedio` y tampoco un valor numérico para dicha columna, pues se supone que eso lo hará el trigger que estas programando
- Además debes declarar la columna `peomedio` como `null` de este modo no será requerida en el proceso del `Insert` y lo podrá generar el disparador

Entonces basándome en lo que entendí de tu ejercicio, el código debería ser el siguiente:

Creación de la tabla:

```
create table prom(
    materia varchar(20),
    c1 float(3),
    c2 float(3),
    c3 float(3),
    c4 float(3),
    promedio float(3) null
);
```

Creación del trigger

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER pumped BEFORE INSERT ON prom
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.promedio = (NEW.c1 + NEW.c2 + NEW.c3 + NEW.c4) / 4;
END;
//
```

Inserción del registro en la tabla:

```
INSERT INTO prom(materia,c1,c2,c3,c4) 
values("ingles",9,5,7,9);
```

Haciendo un `SELECT` para comprobar los valores ingresados:

```
MariaDB [calificaciones]> SELECT * FROM prom;
+---------+------+------+------+------+----------+
| materia | c1   | c2   | c3   | c4   | promedio |
+---------+------+------+------+------+----------+
| ingles  |    9 |    5 |    7 |    9 |      7.5 |
+---------+------+------+------+------+----------+
```